# What are these bright yellow/red/pink colors I get from subtracting two images?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I'm making an Android app, in which the user takes two images and the first is "subtracted" from the second on a pixel-by-pixel basis.

Essentially, the two Bitmaps are converted to 2D int arrays, and the image subtraction is performed using the following method:

```
private int[][] pixelmapDifference(int[][] subtrahend, int[][] minuend) {
    int[][] diff = new int[subtrahend.length][subtrahend[0].length];
    for (int x = 0; x < diff.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < diff[0].length; y++) {
            diff[x][y] = minuend[x][y] - subtrahend[x][y];
        }
    }
    return diff;
}
```

The resultant 2D array is then converted to a Bitmap. This is what the 3 images look like (first, second, and difference).

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I account for this? I'd like to just get the difference between the two, in this case just the water.

Comment: YOu can't just subtract values like that with images.  Describe what you're actually trying to achieve.  Note that computers are REALLY BAD at things like comparing images, because what matters isn't exact values but patterns.  Computer vision to recognize features is still a hot area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting always second from the first. What happens when second one is brighter? Value returned is below zero. I'm not one hundred percent sure what will happen, but documentation says that color is 
`int color = (A & 0xff) << 24 | (R & 0xff) << 16 | (G & 0xff) << 8 | (B & 0xff);`
So as you substract lighter from darker in some situations outcome are these strange dots.

Comment: Check which one is smaller? but that depends what kind of effect you would like to achieve.

Comment: So to clarify, my app might be doing, for example, 23,34,33 (RGB) minus 25,33,32 and the red value is "wrapping around" to 254, right?